# changing the icon theme has no effect (13.04)

Tags: gnome, icons, dconf, gnome-tweak-tool

Using gnome-shell 3.6 on Ubuntu 13.04.

I installed gnome-tweak-tool, and I can use it to change both the shell theme and the  current theme (ie. window borders). However, changing the icon theme has no effect, regardless of whether a system set or custom set is selected. The setting is definitely saved, and I can also see it in dconf. For example:

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/icon-theme
'oxygen'

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
'oxygen'
```

Comment: I also set the gconf key /desktop/gnome/interface/icon_theme just in case, but there's no indication that that is even supposed to affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bother it; if nobody knows how to fix this, I'll simply put absolute paths in all the .desktop files. Simple but effective.